# Why Angular AoT don't supports function expressions in decorators?

Tags: javascript, angular, lambda, functional-programming, angular-aot

Angular AoT compiler throw an error if you try to made a call in a decorator.

consider following code:

```
export function factoryBuilder(config: MyConfig) {
  return function customFactory() {
    return new MyService(config);
  };
}

@NgModule({})
export class MyModule {

  static forRoot(config: MyConfig): ModuleWithProviders {

    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useFactory: factoryBuilder(config),
        }]
    };
  }
}
```

If you try to build it with aot flag (--prod):

Compiler says:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'MyModule'
   ...
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

Can someone explain technically why the compiler can't support that?

PS: This code works in JiT mode.

Comment: Fixable with 'export const myFactory ...' ?

Comment: nope, no matter. i change that. ty

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions (or lambdas) are not supported in modules because AOT compiler needs to be able to analyze the module "statically".

Using a normal `function` instead of arrow function should solve the problem:

```
export function myFactory(config) { };
```

You may also have to do the same thing with the `customFactory` function returned by `myFactory`.

You can find more information about how AOT works in the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) or in this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox).

Comment: the problem is not about the syntax. the compiler complains even if you rewrite with function syntax. The problem is about use an high order function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) . My question is know if do this is technically impossible and why. ty

Comment: I must admit that I don't know the answer for higher order function. I just now that in my app I ended duplicating some code instead of generating it, and that I avoided at maximum these higher order functions

Comment: could you go into a bit more depth with your initial sentence? I understand what static is, but not why it doesn't transpile first , nor why it matters specifically when in a decorator -- lambdas are allowed all-the-heck-over-the-place otherwise (and are in fact transpiled to static functions depending on your angular-cli build target)